# Input File is not a Mach-O file

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms application (UWP, Android and iOS) and wanted to add a Xamarin.MacOS project.
When compiling I get this error and I have no idea how to fix it:

`MMP : error : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: input file: /Projekt 3/Projekt/MTBK/mTiCS.MacOS/bin/Debug/mTiCS.MacOS.app/Contents/MonoBundle/mTiCS.sln is not a Mach-O file`

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in Visual Studio for Mac. I deleted the Xamarin.Mac Project and re-created it and now it works.